# Run custom python script via dolphin (kde-plasma) right-click menu

Tags: kde-plasma, dolphin-browser

I was wondering if the following could be possible in **kde-plasma** and **dolphin** file manager in particular:

> Having a set of files selected, run a python script chosen from the
> right-click menu so as to act on the chosen files (e.g., to rename them, copy them, etc).

I'm not even sure how to look into this, so I thought I could ask here. Thanks!